# Import error while following the django tutorial: No module named urls

Tags: django

I'm trying to follow along with Django's tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

I created my own model, which looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

And my settings.py looks like:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'lcf.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lcf.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'lcf',
)
```

and the urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'tsg.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^tsg/', include('tsg.foo.urls')),

# Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
# url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

But, after running
    `python manage.py syncdb`

and then running 
    `python manage.py runserver`

The browser shows the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'lcf')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/staff/nallurv/Envs/tsg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/home/staff/nallurv/Envs/tsg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  298.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/staff/nallurv/Envs/tsg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  328.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/staff/nallurv/Envs/tsg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  323.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/home/staff/nallurv/Envs/tsg/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named urls
```

Comment: can you describe your project structurte (i.e. what files are in what packages) even a quick screenshot will work?

Comment: You're using the 1.4 release code, but the development tutorial. Don't do that. Use the tutorial at  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Daniel Roseman. I switched, and went through the one specific to 1.4, and still no luck. I seem to be doing everything the tutorial says.

Comment: The project structure looks like: In a directory called 'tsg', I have two directories: 'lcf' and 'tsg' and 'manage.py'. The inner 'tsg' directory contains: __init__.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py. The 'lcf' directory contains: __init__.py, models.py, tests.py, views.py. From the 'lcf' directory, the only file that I've modified is 'models.py'.  I'm not sure how to add a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error (`Exception Value: No module named urls`), but in my case it was when trying to deploy my Django app under Apache with mod_wsgi.  The app ran fine with `python manage.py runserver`.  It turned out that my urls.py file was not readable by the user that Apache was running as.  So, you might want to check the permissions on urls.py to make sure that it is readable by the same user you are logged in as when you run `python manage.py runserver`.  One way to do this would be to run the command `ls -l` which will show the file owner and file permissions.  If that turns out to be the problem, then have the owner of the file (or the root user) run the command `chmod a+r urls.py`.

By the way, the contents of the files you posted look just fine.  It is pretty much the same as what I had except that our project names are different.